# is there sth like profile for firefoxDriver in InternetExplorerDriver in WebDriver?

Tags: profile, webdriver

how can i start the IE with some special plugins?
just like u customize a special profile for firefox in webDriver.

is there something like that?
or maybe there's another way to accomplish that.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't support profiles; any changes such as plugins are global to the user's account. Additionally, since plugins are registry-based, and the settings are stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, they require elevation to administrative privileges to install and configure. These two factors make it impossible to have WebDriver install or configure plugins at runtime. You'll have to manually install the plugin manually before launching your tests.

Comment: so, based on what u said, i guess that there's no way to launch the test and open the IE without any plugins which i had installed before; (i mean, if u installed, like a google bar before u launching a test, and u run the test, what u got is still the IE with the google bar)   Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right. You might be able to go searching through the registry to find the plugin settings, but Selenium will not do it for you.